# Mangled output of accented characters with biblatex-chicago and babel (Brazilian localization, not input)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, babel, biblatex-chicago

I'm having trouble with biblatex-chicago's localized output. Here's  the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{aristoteles1997,
  author =  {Aristóteles},
  title =  {Ação},
  editor =  {John Doe},
  editora = {Jane Doe},
  editoratype = {collaborator},
  publisher =  {Pub Inc},
  year =  1997,
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{aristoteles1997}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I process this file with:

```
pdflatex mwe
biber mwe
pdflatex mwe
pdflatex mwe
```

The resulting bibliography is as follows:

[image: PDF output with mangled accented characters in localization]

As you can see, "Referências", "Aristóteles" and "Ação" are all correctly rendered, and the whole thing is localized, as expected, to Brazilian Portuguese.

But the "Em colaboração com" part ("In collaboration with") is mangled.

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you should file a bug report about this (as it seems to be an error in the biblatex translations).

Comment: Hm, maybe I should! I wasn't sure if this was really a bug or if I was doing something wrong. Is this a bug in biblatex or babel?

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/578

Comment: Hey, thanks, @egreg! And I see the issue is already closed. Nice!

Comment: @cksk Superfast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your own localizations strings (fixes missing ç):

[image: bibliography]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{brazil}{bycollaborator={Em colaboração com}}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{aristoteles1997,
  author =  {Aristóteles},
  title =  {Ação},
  editor =  {John Doe},
  editora = {Jane Doe},
  editoratype = {collaborator},
  publisher =  {Pub Inc},
  year =  1997,
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{aristoteles1997}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great stuff! I can use this while waiting for the fix to arrive (it's already fixed in DEV branch). Thanks!